# Node-Red Dashboard in an WSL envronmend

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dashboard, node-red

I installed Windows WSL debian (newest) and Node-Red (newest) and made some simple tests.
Everythings seems working fine, but not the dashboard.
When I start http://localhost:1880/ui/ the Node-Red-Dashboard appears, but there are no elements I defined to be there.
Has anyone a idea what can be wrong?

Here is my flow:

```
[
{
    "id": "7931864fc4716b90",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "Flow 1a",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "735b6edf0388ecc6",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "7931864fc4716b90",
    "name": "debug 1",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "true",
    "targetType": "full",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 380,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "a35177e0c57e764a",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "7931864fc4716b90",
    "name": "Inject",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "hier kommt ein Text",
    "payload": "Hallo Udo",
    "payloadType": "str",
    "x": 90,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": [
        [
            "28912b9ae8d2d2e7"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "28912b9ae8d2d2e7",
    "type": "change",
    "z": "7931864fc4716b90",
    "name": "change",
    "rules": [
        {
            "t": "set",
            "p": "topic",
            "pt": "msg",
            "to": "outputs",
            "tot": "str"
        },
        {
            "t": "move",
            "p": "payload",
            "pt": "msg",
            "to": "payload2",
            "tot": "msg"
        }
    ],
    "action": "",
    "property": "",
    "from": "",
    "to": "",
    "reg": false,
    "x": 200,
    "y": 240,
    "wires": [
        [
            "735b6edf0388ecc6"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "e462442ef3cc552d",
    "type": "ui_switch",
    "z": "7931864fc4716b90",
    "name": "",
    "label": "Schalter",
    "tooltip": "",
    "group": "9e2ad1fbee3da9eb",
    "order": 0,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "passthru": true,
    "decouple": "false",
    "topic": "topic",
    "topicType": "msg",
    "style": "",
    "onvalue": "true",
    "onvalueType": "bool",
    "onicon": "",
    "oncolor": "",
    "offvalue": "false",
    "offvalueType": "bool",
    "officon": "",
    "offcolor": "",
    "animate": false,
    "className": "",
    "x": 160,
    "y": 380,
    "wires": [
        []
    ]
},
{
    "id": "35fbbcbf70d73cb5",
    "type": "ui_switch",
    "z": "7931864fc4716b90",
    "name": "",
    "label": "Schalter 2",
    "tooltip": "hier kann man Schalten",
    "group": "f08570e8446be245",
    "order": 1,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "passthru": true,
    "decouple": "false",
    "topic": "topic",
    "topicType": "msg",
    "style": "",
    "onvalue": "true",
    "onvalueType": "bool",
    "onicon": "",
    "oncolor": "",
    "offvalue": "false",
    "offvalueType": "bool",
    "officon": "",
    "offcolor": "",
    "animate": false,
    "className": "",
    "x": 160,
    "y": 440,
    "wires": [
        []
    ]
},
{
    "id": "f00afefbc230476e",
    "type": "ui_slider",
    "z": "7931864fc4716b90",
    "name": "",
    "label": "slider",
    "tooltip": "",
    "group": "9e2ad1fbee3da9eb",
    "order": 1,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "passthru": true,
    "outs": "all",
    "topic": "topic",
    "topicType": "msg",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 10,
    "step": 1,
    "className": "",
    "x": 150,
    "y": 500,
    "wires": [
        [
            "b9e75bf6ba9b7b2a"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "7a8c9c58d986c9c9",
    "type": "ui_colour_picker",
    "z": "7931864fc4716b90",
    "name": "",
    "label": "",
    "group": "9e2ad1fbee3da9eb",
    "format": "hex",
    "outformat": "string",
    "showSwatch": true,
    "showPicker": false,
    "showValue": false,
    "showHue": false,
    "showAlpha": false,
    "showLightness": true,
    "square": "false",
    "dynOutput": "false",
    "order": 2,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "passthru": true,
    "topic": "topic",
    "topicType": "msg",
    "className": "",
    "x": 170,
    "y": 560,
    "wires": [
        []
    ]
},
{
    "id": "b9e75bf6ba9b7b2a",
    "type": "ui_gauge",
    "z": "7931864fc4716b90",
    "name": "",
    "group": "9e2ad1fbee3da9eb",
    "order": 3,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "gtype": "gage",
    "title": "gauge",
    "label": "units",
    "format": "{{value}}",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 10,
    "colors": [
        "#00b500",
        "#e6e600",
        "#ca3838"
    ],
    "seg1": "",
    "seg2": "",
    "className": "",
    "x": 350,
    "y": 500,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "9e2ad1fbee3da9eb",
    "type": "ui_group",
    "name": "Group 1",
    "tab": "965e6d7950691f5f",
    "order": 1,
    "disp": true,
    "width": "6",
    "collapse": false,
    "className": ""
},
{
    "id": "f08570e8446be245",
    "type": "ui_group",
    "name": "Group 2",
    "tab": "965e6d7950691f5f",
    "order": 2,
    "disp": true,
    "width": 6
},
{
    "id": "965e6d7950691f5f",
    "type": "ui_tab",
    "name": "Room",
    "icon": "tv",
    "order": 1,
    "disabled": true,
    "hidden": false
}
]
```

The empty dashboard:

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: The flow in the question is missing a `ui_base` node, did you import it from somewhere else into your WSL instance?

Comment: I created the flow in the debian-WSL.

For test I exported the flow into a instance on a Raspberry. It worked very well.

What do I have to do, to get the ui_base node?

Udo

Comment: don#t know why, but it works now.
Thanks